# a non- empty set A of a Banach space is bounded<=> there exists a real number k such that llxll <= k for every x in A.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How to show that, a non- empty set A of a Banach space is bounded<=> there exists a real number k such that  llxll <= k for every x in A.
Note: 
A set A is bounded if diameter of A is finite.
Diameter of A= sup { d(x,y), x,y€A}.
For <= part, I have deduced ,
 diameter of A<= 2k by means of triangle inequality and I think this part does not even need the set to be a subset of the Banach space.
But I am having trouble to prove => part.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, I would have said that the condition on the diameter was a theorem, and the condition on the norm was the definition. The theorem itself does not need you to use the fact that the space is a Banach space. With an unsubstantially different formulation, you could say that it holds in all metric spaces.

Comment: Actually , I also know this.But G.f simmons introduction to topology , in the exercise 15 problem (1) he asks the reader to prove this.I dont understand the necessity of banachness here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your other implication choose $y_0\in A$. Then for every $x\in A$ $$\|x\| \leq \|y_0\|+\|x-y_0\|\leq \|y_0\| + k,$$ where $k  = \sup_{x,y\in A}\|x-y\|$. For $\|y_0\|+k =: a$ we have $\|x\|\leq a$, $x\in A$.

Comment: Where did we use banachness?

Comment: Is every non epmty subset of a banach space , a lunear subspace? It is not, then how x€A and y(0)€ A => ll x-y(0) ll €A?

Comment: $\|x-y\|$ is just the metric defined by the norm and it does not imply that $x-y\in A$.

Comment: Then how are you writing llx-yll<= k

Comment: By assumption the diameter is finite $\sup_{x,y\in A}d(x,y) = \sup_{x,y\in A}\|x-y\| =: k<\infty $